# Alternative for If conditions and replacing it with inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, hashmap, if-case

So my problem is that you have a lot of if conditions to be checked and inside that if condition you have multiple lines of code. I want to eliminate it and use inheritance instead. For every if statement I will be using a separate class to handle it. This is more like a derivative of the command pattern but not command pattern itself.

I have an interface which contains only one method which defines the task i want it to be implemented. I have an abstract class implementing that interface and contains a static map and static methods to add values and retrieves the task. The classes i specified will be extending this **Handler** class.

**This is my scenario.**

I am sending a string as parameter to get a specific translator. Let's  say sinhala or tamil or english. On each implementation of those translators, I will be adding the necessary values to the map in the **Handler** class in a static block. Basically adding them in the class load time.

Below is my code.

**Command Interface**

```
public interface Command {
    LanguageTranslator getLangTranslator();
}
```

**Handler Abstract class**

```
public abstract class Handler implements Command {

    private static Map<String, Command> map = new HashMap<>();


    public static void AddToMap(String key, Command command){

        map.put(key,command);
    }
    public static LanguageTranslator getTranslator(String value) throws Exception {
        if (!(map.containsKey(value))){
            throw new LanguageNotFoundException("Translator not found");
        }else {
            return map.get(value).getLangTranslator();
        }
    }


}
```

**Sinhala Translator**

```
public class SiCommand extends Handler {
    static {
        Handler.AddToMap("1",new SiCommand());
    }

    @Override
    public LanguageTranslator getLangTranslator() {
        return new SiTranslator();
    }
```

}

**Tamil Translator**

```
public class TiCommand extends Handler {
    static {
        Handler.AddToMap("2",new TiCommand());
    }

    @Override
    public LanguageTranslator getLangTranslator() {
        return new TiTranslator();
    }
```

}

**English Translator**

```
public class EnCommand extends Handler {
    static {
        Handler.AddToMap("3",new EnCommand());
    }

@Override
    public LanguageTranslator getLangTranslator() {
        return new EnTranslator();
    }
```

}

**Demo**

```
 RowTranslator rowTranslator = Handler.getTranslator("2");
```

**Questions**

Since All values are assigned to the map during the class loadding time these are my questions

1. Is using static blocks like this a good practice ?
2. I want to eliminate the use of if conditions as i mentioned before. By using this method when ever someone wants to add a new if condition, you just only have to create a new class extending handler and implement it. Therefore the outside user doesn't need to know the internal handling of the **Command**'s sub classes. The output is just gonna be a translator. Is this a good way of doing it? What are the better alternatives? What should be adjusted?

**Note**

Also I will be focusing strictly on **Open/Close** principle as well

Comment: I don't see why you need to inherit from the `Handler` (which is basically a factory). Just having access to the private member does not justify inheritance, in my opinion. You may just want to give the handler a `registerTranslator()` method, which is then called from the static block. It is probably also cleaner to do the registration explicitly at application startup, but this is probably a matter of personal preference.